# Full text search File Explorer

Tags: file-system, file-management

I want a full text search File manager for my Nexus 7. Lifehacker writes about ES but after trying it out, it doesn't do full text search http://lifehacker.com/5825578/the-best-file-management-app-for-android

What would be your choice? I have mostly .txt and .pdf files (also some .tex but that would classify as plain text I guess).

I have tried [Searcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apppie.ase&hl=sv) but I'm not satisfied.

Comment: Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details). You might wish to consult [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) to find a fitting place for your question.

Comment: While an app is being requested, I think there's a fairly clear problem to be solved. I think this question is _okay_. @user1603548: You might want to have a look at [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a product?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1289)

Comment: @Poldie: Very often the solution to a problem is an app. That's okay. What we have trouble with (although not in this case, I don't think) is people who've decided on their solution (an app) and ask about that ("What's the best app to do X?") instead of the problem they're trying to solve. That tends to lead to short answers with no real information and people simply offering their favorite app.